# Jedis Pub/Sub Value of Key

Tags: java, redis, publish-subscribe, jedis

Is there any way to multicast the value of a changed key with Jedis pub/sub?

I'm currently running:

```
jedis.psubscribe(new MyListener(), "__key*__:*");
```

And I get messages such as:

```
onPMessage pattern __key*__:* __keyspace@0__:testTag0 set
onPMessage pattern __key*__:* __keyevent@0__:set testTag0
onPMessage pattern __key*__:* __keyspace@0__:testTag0 del
onPMessage pattern __key*__:* __keyevent@0__:del testTag0
```

I would also like to get a message over Jedis pub/sub with the value of the key that was set. For example, something like:

```
onPMessage pattern __key*__:* __keyevent@0__:set testTag0 tagValue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is a somewhat common need, keyspace notifications do not include the actual values, hence what you're looking for isn't possible.